# Copying only non-empty cells into the HTML object which is being sent vie e-mail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail-api

I have a script that copies a table from a Google Sheet into an e-mail which is being sent automatically every day (there is a trigger). The table always starts in the cell K1 and it always has 6 columns, however, the number of rows is always different. I want to account for it and make it sorta dynamic. Here is the google script:

```
function CheckShare() {
  // Fetch the monthly sales
  var Range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Daily AA Catergory Share").getRange("I2"); 
  var result = Range.getValue();
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Daily AA Catergory Share").getRange("K1:P10").getValues();


  var TABLEFORMAT = 'cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" dir="ltr" border="1" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;font-size:10pt;font-family:arial,sans,sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #ccc;font-weight:normal;color:black;background-color:white;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;'

  var htmltable = '<table ' + TABLEFORMAT +' ">';

for (row = 0; row<data.length; row++){

htmltable += '<tr>';

for (col = 0 ;col<data[row].length; col++){
  if (data[row][col] === "" || 0) {htmltable += '<td>' + 'None' + '</td>';} 
  else
    if (row === 0)  {
      htmltable += '<th>' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
    }

  else {htmltable += '<td>' + data[row][col] + '</td>';}
}

     htmltable += '</tr>';
}

     htmltable += '</table>';
     Logger.log(data);
     Logger.log(htmltable);
  // Check totals sales
  if (result >0){
    // Fetch the email address
      var emailAddress = "reports@gmail.com";
    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = 'There are ' + result +' deviating metrics: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AQEBTt919TIu92Gb9TeZRD3KpSm3L_WCHgTOmw/edit#gid=1525731698'
    + ' See the dashboard here: <link> ';
    var subject = 'Transaction Monitoring Alert: AA Share';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {htmlBody:htmltable});
    }
}
```

The current e-mail output looks likes this: [image]

I want it to exclude rows with values "None" (empty cells)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.getDataRange()` rather than `.getRange("K1:P10")`, this should only return rows with actual data.

```
var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Daily AA Catergory Share").getDataRange().getValues();
```

**Edit:**

Since you can't use `.getDataRange()` to achieve your goal. Try using `.getLastRow()` instead then passing that to your `getRange()`. The below code should get the range of K1:Px (x = however many rows of data you have).

```
var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Daily AA Catergory Share");
var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
var data = dataSheet.getRange(1, 11, lastRow, 6).getValues();
```

Comment: Hey @ross, thanks for the suggestion, but the problem is that there is also other data in columns A:F, for example, which I don't want to include in the email. I only want to include data that is in columns K:P.

Comment: No worries - you're right `getDataRange()` would get too much data if you have data in the other columns. I've edited my answer and included a solution that uses `getLastRow()` instead, have a look and see if that helps you.

Comment: Hey @ross, unfortunately this didn't help either. If for instance tables in columns A:F has 10 rows, this script will take 10 rows also from columns K:P, even though there might be data only in the first 4 rows in columns K:P.

Comment: Hey @ross, I just made it work. Essentially I used your code, but I simply moved the table I want to send in the email to a separate tab. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great! I had been pulling my hair out trying to find a way to filter out all of the empty values but that works too. What a relief.